# Cannot convert gsm to unicode

Tags: unicode, sms, gsm, smpp, kannel

Dears

I am using kannel 1.5.0 gateway with smpp on RHEL6 and when I receive an sms I get these errors:

```
2016-01-28 13:28:07 [8613] [6] WARNING: Could not convert GSM (0xd4) to Unicode.
2016-01-28 13:28:07 [8613] [6] WARNING: Could not convert GSM (0xf2) to Unicode.
.....
```

and I receive the messages incorrectly to my application, here is the request captured:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9091/services/smsReceive?msisdn=%2B353872849216&coding=0&smsText=%C3%85%3CH%C3%B9a%C3%91%C3%B9%25evM%C3%B9)zX%C3%ACp&DCS=-1&charset=UTF-8'
```

and this is my kannel configuration:

```
group = core
admin-port = 13001
smsbox-port = 13002
admin-password = bar
log-file = "/home/user/logs/kannellogs/SmscGateway.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1;172.*.*.*;192.*.*.*;10.*.*.*"
admin-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1;172.*.*.*;192.*.*.*;10.*.*.*"
admin-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
access-log = "/home/user/logs/kannellogs/access.log"

# SMSBOX SETUP
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13013
log-file="/home/user/logs/kannellogs/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log="/home/user/logs/kannellogs/sms_access.log"
reply-couldnotfetch = "Service is down, please try again later.(notfetch)"
reply-couldnotrepresent = "Service is down, please try again later.(notrepresent)"
reply-requestfailed = "Service is down, please try again later.(failed)"
reply-emptymessage = ""
mo-recode = true

# SEND-SMS USERS
group = sendsms-user
username=test
password=test
user-allow-ip = "*.*.*.*"
concatenation = true
split-chars = "#!^&*("
max-messages = 10

# SMPP PARAMETERS for SMSC account
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id =Smsc12345
smsc-username = Voda
smsc-password = 12345678
host = 123.222.111.11
port = 1040
system-type = Vodafone403
interface-version = 34
source-addr-autodetect = false
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
reconnect-delay = false
reconnect-delay = 10
transceiver-mode = true
throughput = 10
address-range = "^12345$"
max-pending-submits = 3

group = sms-service
accepted-smsc = "Smsc12345"
keyword = default
get-url = "http://127.0.0.1:9091/services/smsReceive?msisdn=%p&coding=%c&smsText=%a&DCS=%m&charset=%C"
catch-all=true
max-messages = 0
```

I am new to kannel please help if i am doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should check Kannel docs;

for a "normal" message, it will be "GSM" (coding=0), "binary" (coding=1) or "UTF-16BE" (coding=2)

What I see in url is that

```
&coding=0
```

what should be:

```
&coding=2
```

and also take care that it is url encoded correctly and about length of unicode message (if you are using aggregators not all support concatenation and long messages)

Hope it helps.

Vedran